# Filtering questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Before asking a question, I am trying to ensure that it is not a duplicate, by searching accepted answers.

I click the appropriate tag, select filter and see ...

[image: image of Software Recommendations StackExchange search GUI]

In case, it's not clear, I added the check to choose to search for questions which have an accepted answer (it might even be nice to sort for the most upvoted accepted answer, but maybe that is asking too much?).

BTW, I am aware that I can use `isanswered:`, `isaccepted:`, `hasaccepted:`, etc, but 1) I always forget those & have to search for them - many users will not even be aware of them, and 2) why have a GUI if we are going to rely on the [boolean operators](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/searching), especially if it is missing what is arguably the most important  option - "find me something that works"?

Or, have I just embarrassed myself by typing all of that after missing something glaringly obvious (which is always a strong possibility with me :-) ?

Comment: *"I always forget those & have to search for them - many users will not even be aware of them"* - I have the same experience.  I know they exist, but I always have to look them up to remember the exact strings.  It doesn't help that SE uses "isanswered" and "hasaccepted", instead of "hasanswers" and "hasaccepted".  But that's what happens when you don't hire qualified UX/UI experts and perform real usability testing. ;)

Comment: Lol. Are you offering your services? ;-)  I am surprised, though, about the lack of consistency across sites. I would have expected them just to use S.O as a template for each new site

Comment: I would be willing to help them, but they've never asked, and I've never formally offered.  Even as one of their moderators, they barely have any direct communication with me.  I did offer to dark theme all their sites at one time, but I never heard back.  I agree, SE definitely needs to work on their UX.  I use SE much more than the average person, and it's not uncommon for me to have to scratch my head trying to figure out how to complete a basic task.  I wouldn't be surprised if many people just give up and go to non-SE sites for help.  That said, SE does have plenty of *potential!* :)

Comment: Let's hope that S.E doesn't do something like SourceForge- or `Expert sex change`   (although they came pretty close with Monica - did she ever come back?)

Comment: I think what separates SE/SO from all other similar sites is that most big search engines have a strong bias in favoring SE/SO content (so much so, I find it a bit concerning because it makes it hard for similar sites to have a chance to succeed; also many posts & accepted answers on SE/SO are woefully outdated, whereas other sites have fresher content... this is actually another big UX issue that needs work at SE/SO). Regarding Monica, I'm not sure, but I think I read that she didn't want to volunteer as a SE moderator anymore after how she was treated. I didn't follow that mess too closely.